# Text editor that would allow jumping to line 12,250,758,440 of a 170GB / 22,843,445,311-line file

Tags: windows, linux, text-editor, plain-text

I need to work with a rather large file

I heard good things about UltraEdit and it seemed promising, it's able to open the file, but it turns out that it can't jump to line numbers higher than 2^32 (2,147,483,648)

which is less than 18% of where I need to go

I'll potentially need to edit the line, not just view it, but I don't know exactly what kind of edit I'll need to make until I get there, I just know there's a problem there that needs to be investigated.

I'm on Windows, but CLI Linux programs would also be acceptable as long as they're usable via WSL. No GUI Linux programs.

Comment: Other than UltraEdit, what have you tried, and what were the limitations you ran into?

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at commercial code "crisp" text editor. Runs on windows and linux and is a gui.  I only use linux. I have not found a file size limi to load a file either in width (columns) or length (lines)..  I don't know "jump to line" range of applicability but I have no really huge fies to test with.  Has every conceiveable editing and macro feature. including hexidecimal editing.  It is based upon old brief editor.  Probably a test download for a trial.  See: https://crisp.com

Answer (score 1):

[EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/large-file-support/files-up-to-248gb/) claims it can open up to 16TB files and the [docs](http://www.emeditor.org/en/cmd_edit_jump.html#:%7E:text=EmEditor%20Home%20-%20EmEditor%20Help%20-%20Command%20Reference,Commands:%20Edit%20%3E%20Advanced%20%3E%20Jump%20%E2%80%A2%20Toolbar:) say you can jump to specific lines

Does require a subscription ~$40/year at time of posting